# How does rads.stackoverflow clicking work?

Tags: discussion

This Electronics SE [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/364144/102305) includes a link to an example solution. The link entered in the text of the answer is

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01G5SUZEG/
```

and is displayed like that as well.

But the link given to my browser is

```
https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G5SUZEG
```

I'm just curious what this is called, and if SO is able to generate revenue or other side benefits from clicks on this.